# DataGrid с автогенерацией столбцов

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть класс

```
class Sample
{
    public double[] data;
    public string Name;
    public bool UsingFlag;
}
```

Мне нужна таблица в которой колонки будут с именем и чекбоксом привязанные к Name и UsingFlag соответственно.

Изображение-иллюстрация того, что хочу
[image: Как это должно выглядеть]

У меня уже готова функция которая возвращает мне массив Sample[], посредством считывания из файла.

На примере показано, что произойдет если попался лишний сепаратор. (создастся еще одна выборка всего с одним элементов).

Мне нужно сделать:
Удаление ячейки(со смещением влево), редактирование ячейки, удаление строки.
Так же, если я удалю пустую ячейку во второй выборке, после смещения влево выборка 3 проверяется на наличие элементов и, если она пуста, колонка "Выборка 3" полностью удаляется.

UsingFlag должен быть привязан к чекбоксу. Это нужно для фильтрации(если нужно считывание не всех выборок из файла).

Comment: Что значит "по строкам для каждой колонки должен идти массив data"?

Comment: В выборке разное количество элементов?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, да.

Comment: Думаю, DataGrid здесь не подойдет, но с помощью пары вложенных ItemsControl можно всё организовать

Comment: Напишите какой конкретно функционал требуется в итоге. Нужна ли возможность менять имя, ставить флажок? Менять количество чисел в массиве? Редактировать сами числа?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, добавил описание нужного функционала

Comment: @АндрейNOP почему не подойдет? Подойдет, но нужно будет событие генерации столбцов обрабатывать.

Comment: Очень плохое описание. Трудно понять что-либо. Из того, что понял: 1) текстовой файл со строками в виде чисел, разделенных неким сепаратором; 2) числа могут быть успешно считаны как double, но могут быть и опечатки и тогда с этим надо что-то делать; 3) визуально требуется отображать считанные строки в виде столбцов, у которых есть заголовок с чекбоксом, которому соответствует класс `Sample`. Уфф. А какую функциональность несет в себе поле `UsingFlag`, кроме того, что оно связано с чекбоксом? На что должно влиять вкл./выкл. чекбокса? Перепишите свое описание функциональности более понятно.

Comment: @Bulson, исправил. Теперь лучше?